# Cart value unchanged in iPhone with paypal integration

Tags: iphone, paypal

Currently I am working on the one commerce application in iPhone.

I integrated MECL (PayPal library for mobile express checkout library) to my application and it works.

I also got the `deviceReferenceToken`, `ExpressCheckoutToken`, `TransactionId` & `PayerId`.

My question is: how can I use these variables in my application to get empty cart value?

Do I need web service for that? If so then what type of Web service is it?

Also I used PayPal demoproject from MECL Example Non-Web Project.